# How do I know if a Coroutine is still "waiting"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

All I can find online is "How to check if a coroutine is running", which is not what I want.

Say if I have a coroutine with

```
yield return new WaitUntil(()=> SomeBool);
```

Is there a way to know if this statement is still "pending"?

Because if I use the Boolean trick such as

```
isRunning = true;
yield return new WaitUntil(()=>SomeBool);
isRunning = false;
```

The `isRunning` flag will "always" be `true` if I stop the coroutine before `SomeBool` is set to `true`.

I have tested that this is indeed the case! Anything after the `yield` statement will never be run!

And since it's never ran, any checking is useless, whether it's `isRunning` or `SomeBool`.

So it failed the function of "Checking if the coroutine is still running"!

Is there a way to "do the right job"?

So if I finally set `SomeBool` to `true` from another part of the code, I know that there is still a `WaitUntil` waiting for it? If not, then somehow restart the coroutine so it won't "stuck forever and crash the game"!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: "The isRunning flag will "always" be true if I stop the coroutine before SomeBool is set to true, correct?" What makes you think that's the case?  Did you actually perform the test and find out what actually happens?

Comment: Actually, I did! It IS the case! "ANYTHING" after the yield statement is NEVER run!

Comment: You already have access to ```SomeBool```, can't you just look at that?

Comment: @Immersive Because... if `SomeBool` is `false`, `isRunning` is `true`, and if you stop the coroutine right now, 'isRunning` will still be `true` while the coroutine is already stopped! Wrong! And if `SomeBool` is `true`, then the coroutine finished, but `SomeBool` is still `true`, Wrong! Let me see how can I reword my question.

Comment: @Servy Has the question been updated to be clear enough? I think it makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`CustomYieldInstruction.keepWaiting`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction-keepWaiting.html). Make the object you `yield return` available outside the coroutine and things can check if the coroutine would wait if it were to be checked right now:

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    CustomYieldInstruction waitTest;
    Coroutine waitingCoroutine;
    bool waitBool;

    void Start()
    {
        waitBool = false;
        waitingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(WaitingCoroutine());
        StartCoroutine(TriggeringCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitingCoroutine()
    {
        waitTest = null;
        yield return waitTest;

        waitTest = new WaitUntil(() => waitBool);
        yield return waitTest;

        waitTest = new WaitUntil(() => waitBool);
        yield return waitTest;

        waitingCoroutine = null;
    }
 
    private IEnumerator TriggeringCoroutine()
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("First frame waiting: {0}", IsWaiting())); // false
        yield return null;

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Second frame waiting: {0}", IsWaiting())); // true
        yield return null;

        waitBool = true;
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Third frame waiting: {0}", IsWaiting())); // false
        yield return null;

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Fourth frame waiting: {0}", IsWaiting())); // false
        yield return null;

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Fifth frame waiting: {0}", IsWaiting())); // false

    }

    private bool IsWaiting()
    {
        return waitingCoroutine != null && waitTest != null && waitTest.keepWaiting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this is beyond my skill, could you please be so kind and explain it for me? Much appreciated!

Comment: Everything you need to do is in `IsWaiting` and `WaitingCoroutine`. I'm not really sure what else I can add unless you ask specific questions.

Comment: this will not work if "yield break" is used

Comment: @Andrew Interesting use case. Use `waitTest = null;` or `waitingCoroutine = null;` before `yield break;`, depending on the details of your use case.